# ACTION_USER_PRESENT isn't received when "Automatically lock after n seconds"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen

So I registered `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`, `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` inside a service.

```
IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, screenStateFilter);
```

Here are some situations:

1. **[Correct]** *User's "**Screen lock**" = **None**:* When I press power button, both `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` is received.
2. **[Correct]** *User's "**Screen lock**" = **Swipe**:* When I press power button, the lock screen is shown and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` is received. After unlocking `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` is received.
3. **[Correct]** *User's "**Screen lock**" = **Pattern/PIN/Password** & **Automatically lock** = **Immediately**:* When I press power button, the lock screen is shown and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` is received. After unlocking `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` is received.
4. **[Incorrect]** *User's "**Screen lock**" = **Pattern/PIN/Password** & **Automatically lock** = **15 seconds**:* When I lock the screen and unlock after 15 sec, the lock screen is shown and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` is received. After unlocking `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` is received. **But when I lock the screen and unlock before 15 sec, no lock screen is shown (as expected) but only `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` is received. No ACTION_USER_PRESENT is received.**

So how can I ensure a method will be called when (user unlocked screen) / (`ACTION_SCREEN_ON` when screen is still unlocked).

I've tried

```
KeyguardManager mKeyguard = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if (!mKeyguard.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // Call method
    }
}

if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
    // Call method
}
```

But the method will be called twice during 3 **[Correct]** situation above.

---

**Note**: here is a screenshot for "Automatically lock after n seconds":

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [KeyGuardManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html)

Listen for ACTION_SCREEN_ON and then check if the device is locked, if so, wait for ACTION_USER_PRESENT, otherwise run your code immediately.